# Radio Buttons to select specific text inputs during checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, radio-button, checkout, woocommerce

I am adding custom fields to my checkout area in WooCommerce through my child theme's functions.php. I have added some text inputs, but I need to add two radio buttons that will select/ activate two seperate "sets" of text inputs.

Basically I need a way for my customers to be able to select Button A: enter payment info **OR** select Button B: and enter a PO Number. I need to make sure that the button that is **NOT** selected will not write to the database and hold up / produce errors during checkout.

If you go to the [products page](http://devlabstorage.ltyc.org/products) and add a product, then navigate to the [checkout area](http://devlabstorage.ltyc.org/checkout/) you can see what I have already done. The code is below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');
function custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="payment_info"><h3>'.__('Payment Information').'</h3>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'credit_card_name', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Name on Credit Card'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __(''),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'credit_card_name' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'card_type', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array(''),
    'label'         => __('Card Type'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __(''),
    'options'     => array(
    'American Express' => __('American Express'),
    'Discover' => __('Discover'),
    'Mastercard' => __('Mastercard'),
    'Visa' => __('Visa')
    )), $checkout->get_value( 'card_type' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'card_number', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array(''),
    'label'         => __('Card Number'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'card_number' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'card_expiration_month', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('form-row-first'),
    'label'         => __('Expiration Month'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __('- Select Month -'),
    'options'     => array(
    '1' => __('1'),
    '2' => __('2'),
    '3' => __('3'),
    '4' => __('4'),
    '5' => __('5'),
    '6' => __('6'),
    '7' => __('7'),
    '8' => __('8'),
    '9' => __('9'),
    '10' => __('10'),
    '11' => __('11'),
    '12' => __('12')
    )), $checkout->get_value( 'card_expiration_month' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'card_expiration_year', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('form-row-last'),
    'label'         => __('Expiration Year'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __('- Select Year -'),
    'options'     => array(
    '2013' => __('2013'),
    '2014' => __('2014'),
    '2015' => __('2015'),
    '2016' => __('2016'),
    '2017' => __('2017'),
    '2018' => __('2018'),
    '2019' => __('2019'),
    '2020' => __('2020')
    )), $checkout->get_value( 'card_expiration_year' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'security_code', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('form-row-first'),
    'label'         => __('Security Code'),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder'       => __(''),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'security_code' ));

woocommerce_form_field( 'order_number', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('PO Number (if required)'),
    'placeholder'       => __(''),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'order_number' ));

echo '</div>';
```

So it needs to look like this:

*Payment Information*

[x] Credit Card
Name [ __ active input area __ ]
Card Number [ __ active input area __ ]
etc.

[ _ ] PO Number
Enter Number [ __ inactive input area __ ]

Answer (score 0):

In woocommerce the is no hook to change your form in this way.

**1.** You will have to add the fields to form-billing.php (copy woocommerce/templates/chechout/form-billing.php to {yourtheme}/checkout/form-billing.php). This file contains a foreach-loop which add your fields to the form. Add your custom fields in or after this loop. Example:

```
<?php foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field) : ?>

    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

<?
if($key=='billing_first_name')
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<?
}
?>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can also add jQuery here (after the foreach loop) to show / hide some fields based on the selecting of the user. Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('input[name="gender"]').live('change', function(){ alert('gender checked');});
 </script>
```

**2** Check the input of your custom field(s) after submit. Add this to your functions.php example:

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if($_POST['gender']=='male') 
        {
        $woocommerce->add_error( 'You are a female' );
        }   
}
```

**3** add the input to the database, example:

```
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['gender']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Gender', esc_attr($_POST['gender']));
}
```

See also: https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1604009 for more example code